# How to render two uiOutput in order not synchronistically in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, uioutput

when input$variable change
uiOutput(1) and uiOutput(2) are rendered at the same time?
Is there any way render step by step not synchronistically?

The following is the steps I want.

1) input variable change

2) uiOutput(1) rendering

3) uiOutput(2) rendering

when input variable change shiny page is not working properly.
but after resizing the page window, the screen appears correctly.
Each time I change the input value, i have to recalibrate the page size.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(  
  radioButtons(inputId = "sidebar_data_sell", 
               label = "", 
               choices = c("Sell-in" = "sell_in", "Sell-out" = "sell_out"),
               selected = "sell_out", 
               inline = TRUE),
  uiOutput("summary_sidebar_ui")
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = h5("Hi")),
  sidebar,
  uiOutput("dashboard_body")
)
```

server.R

```
convertMenuItem <- function(mi, tabName) {
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle'] = "tab"
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
  mi
}

out_product_main <- function() {
  list(
    fluidPage(h5("product")))
}

product_items <- function() {
  list(
    selectInput("product_product_sell", 
                "product", 
                choices = list("product1" = "prd1", "product2" = "prd2"), 
                selected = c("prd1"))
  )
}

in_overview_main <- function() {
  list(
    fluidPage(h5("overview")))
}

overview_items <- function() {
  list(
    radioButtons("overview_period_sell", 
                 "period", 
                 choices = c("year","month"), 
                 inline = TRUE, 
                 selected = "month")
  )
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$summary_sidebar_ui <- renderUI({
    if (input$sidebar_data_sell == "sell_in")
    {
      sidebarMenu(id = "summary_item",
                  convertMenuItem(menuItem("Overview", 
                                           tabName = "in_overview",
                                           icon = icon("signal", lib = 'font-awesome'),
                                           overview_items()),
                                  tabName = 'in_overview'))
    }
    else{
      sidebarMenu(id = "p_analysis_item",
                  convertMenuItem(menuItem("Product", 
                                           tabName = "out_product", 
                                           icon = icon("product-hunt", lib='font-awesome'), 
                                           product_items()), 
                                  tabName = 'out_product')
      )
    }


  })

  output$dashboard_body <- renderUI({
    if (input$sidebar_data_sell == "sell_in") {
      dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem("in_overview", in_overview_main())))
    }
    else {
      dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem("out_product", out_product_main())))
    }
  })

})
```

Comment: What's input$sidebar_data_sell, convertMenuItem, in_overview_main? 
Is it possible to simplify the code, that we can test it?

Comment: Use `Sys.sleep()` in one of those?

Comment: @JohnCoene Thank you but, Sys.sleep() is not working properly.

Comment: @CClaire I edit the post code simply as i can.

Comment: You need to pass the number of milliseconds to  the function, i.e. `Sys.sleep(5000)` for 5 seconds